# Running a controller Unit Test works in IntelliJ but not using grails test-app

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I am facing a small challenge on which i do not know how to tackle it. In my current application we are using RabbitMQ as an AMQP broker (using ​**spring-rabbit**​) and we successfully have written integration-tests where the RabbitMQ ConnectionFactory gets autowired etc.

Now we also have some Unit Tests for a small controller which give me an error when I run them using the command-line
`grails test-app`

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'rabbitMQConfig': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
>   rabbitmq.config.RabbitMQConfig.connectionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

When i **​run the Unit Test inside IntelliJ all works fine**!

So i am wondering what the difference is between running the tests inside IntelliJ and the Grails command line. I guess it has something todo with the Environments that Grails runs the test in. But we also have wired up a RabbitMQTestConfig so the integration tests work with the test configuration.

I am a bit puzzled on why this works inside IntelliJ and not on the command-line. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "run the unit test inside IntelliJ", you mean running the Gradle 'test' task (since you're using Grails 3)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define your mocked injection with doWithSpring in your spec :

```
// define the mock or the object instance you want
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = Mock(ConnectionFactory) 
def doWithSpring = {
  connectionFactory(InstanceFactoryBean, connectionFactory, ConnectionFactory)
}
```

If it's not the solution you can try to run clean before testing again